# How can I prevent my wireless mouse from waking my Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, power-management, wireless-mouse

My mouse is so sensitive that it randomly wakes my computer up even when I don't touch the mouse.  I don't want this to happen, so I want to disable the mouse's ability to wake the computer.

I know it's the mouse waking the computer because I ran `powercfg -lastwake`.

So I've tried this:

1. Click Start.
2. Type "cmd" into the Search box.
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter
4. Click "Run as Administrator".
5. Type the following command and press Enter:
      `powercfg -devicedisablewake "HID-compliant mouse"`

I get this error:

> You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake.

So instead I go into `Device Manager` > `Mice and other pointing devices` > `HID-compliant mouse` and uncheck the box (within the mouse configuration) that says `Allow this device to wake the computer`.

When I run `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`, nothing appears, which is good.

So for a while, the next few sleep sessions are fine, and the mouse doesn't wake the computer.

But then eventually something rechecks that checkbox (`Allow this device to wake the computer`) and so my ultra-sensitive mouse starts waking the computer from sleep all the time*.  I can't seem to get the checkbox to stay empty.  Any ideas?

P.S. I have a Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 7000 and a computer running Windows 7.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it causing your problem, but I feel the need to let you know that this was one of the most well-constructed questions I've seen on StackExchange lately.

Comment: I would just turn the mouse off if it has on/off switch which most of wireless mice have.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not windows 98 or XP anymore, when you set an option and it does just that. Now all kind of smarty-pants applications interfere with same device, every single option I set in windows 7 is unreliable.

Comment: adrianTNT: Windows XP was the best desktop OS world ever had. M$ folks has overdone it and spoiled Windows 8 and they are trying to put some soothing touch by fixing some glaring problems of Win 8 in Windows 2010, but that is not really making big difference. Can't Microsoft provide a Win XP like theme or Windows Shell in Windows 2010 to make it appear like XP? Of course they can, it's not hard. But for reason best known to M$ inner circle, they are not doing so. Or have they gone out of their * mind?

Answer (score 2):

Low tech solution: Put the mouse upside down on your table when its not in use. This prevents the optics from detecting any movement.

Comment: This is a hilariously clever solution. I've done this before, although having the bright light from the mouse shining around can be annoying when you aren't using the computer. It's also a bit of an annoyance to have to remember to do this, but hey, it's definitely one solution!

Comment: It seems like the solution to “having the bright light from the mouse shining around” might be to put a dark cloth over it. Which makes me wonder whether you might be able to get the same effect by putting the mouse, right-side-up, ***on*** a dark cloth. Ideally something thick (like felt), so it would absorb any vibrations.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into Device Manager (use Search to find it)
2. Find your mouse under "Mice and other pointing devices"
3. Right-click it and choose Properties
4. Go to the Power Management tab
5. Untick the "Allow this device to wake the computer" checkbox.
6. Click OK.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, the checkbox is unchecked but my mouse still wakes up my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This may work, reboot and go to your bios.
In the BIOS/cmos -Power Management Setup- section will be a list of actions that will start your machine network, mouse power on, keyboard power on, etc-move the mouse setting to disabled.

Hope this fixes it to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

UAC settings keeping changes from sticking? You are administrator? Try setting it from safe mode. Turn off automatic updates at least for the mouse.

Use GUI instead of CLI:
Change Advanced Power Settings, USB settings: disable "allow to wake" for the mouse.

Do you use CCleaner or the like? It could be erasing some settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the number displayed along with the device; `powercfg -devicedisablewake "HID-compliant mouse (006)"` instead.  I've also found some devices which support both a mouse and keyboard need to have both device types disabled (i.e., if "keyboard" is enabled, the mouse still wakes the computer).

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7, standard PS/2 keyboard, usb wireless mouse
HID mouse driver Power Management wake up event turn off didn't work.
The usb wireless dongle has also a keyboard HID driver (even if a wireless keyboard isn't present).
Solution: Device Manager > Keyboards has two devices:

- HID Keyboard device
- Standard PS/2 Keyboard
  Turn off Power Management wake up event for the HID Keyboard device. (The HID mouse turned off also)

The check box rechecks when the driver update, you change the usb port